# How to minimize a text editor and still be able to type

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard, text-editors

I want to make notes while watching a video in fullscreen , I don't want to split the screens. What I want is that I should be able to type in the contents of the text editior while still viewing the video in fullscreen. Is there any way to achieve this? 
Answers for any OS are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr01's answer will work and is simple (+1).  However, I want to point out there are alternatives.

One alternative would be a 2nd monitor.  Have the video on one screen and your notes on the other.

Depending on your video player, it might have an option to always be the top most window, thus allowing you to have your editor in focus, yet still be below the video player.  If your video player doesnt have this option, there is software that sets a window to always be on top, regardless of focus.  Here is one [example](http://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/index.asp) for Windows.  Set your video player to be on top and even though your note taking program has foucs, it is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Just drag the full-sized editor windows out of the screen, leaving out only a tiny part, so it is out of the way of the video. As long as you keep the focus on it, you can continue typing notes.

Comment: This answer reeks of someone who has dealt with this in the past... +1